# Api call request limit of 1 call each hour

Tags: javascript, angularjs, api

I use an API in Switzerland, which allows me to request the api one time every hour in production.

I don't need more than one request each week, since it's event data, but I don't know what i have to do that i can use this api for 200+ users each day.

Do I have to save the data somewhere like firebase or are there services for this? I'm very new in this field. Could you give me a hint?

Comment: You need a serverside code. Somewhere to store it and make a request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Building on top of what Dr. cool said, you'll most likely want to use cron jobs: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/scheduling-tasks-with-cron-jobs--net-8800

Also keep in mind, some API's do not allow you to store the data they provide on your own server. Make sure you read the terms of use before doing so from the API provider.

Comment: This would probably be easiest to go out and download the file and serve it statically with a web server.

Answer (score 1):

It's better to have a program on the server that can run once a week and load data from the API.  This data should be saved in a database.  Then when one of your users needs the data, it's ready to load from your database without hitting the API limit.

Yes, Firebase is a great option.  Or you can use MySQL or other server-side databases.